# i try to make gallery view using photoswipe.com js , when i insert dynamic div then it lost functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i try to make gallery view using photoswipe.com js when am insert dynamic div  then it lost functionality,images are visible but not click able  plz help

```
<body >

<div id="Header">
<a href="http://www.codecomputerlove.com"><img    src="images/codecomputerlovelogo.gif" width="230" height="48" alt="Code Computerlove"    /></a>
</div>

<div id="MainContent">

<div class="page-content">
    <h1>PhotoSwipe</h1>
</div>


<div id="Gallery">

    <div id="gal" class="gallery-row">


<script>      
var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&   api_key=008f6dbb151fa0d6afdacea3ff6ef51f&user_id=125323824@N04";
var src;
$.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
    src = "http://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+ item.id   +"_"+ item.secret +"_s.jpg";
    srcc = "http://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+   item.id +"_"+ item.secret +"_n.jpg";

 $(".gallery-row").append('<div class="gallery-item"><a href="'srcc'"><img   src="'+src+'" /></a></div>');     


    if ( i == 5 ) return false;
});
});
</script>
```

-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/62Eca/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/photoswipe.css" />        
        <script src="http://thecodingwebsite.com/tutorials/photoswipe/klass.min.js"></script>                    
        <script src="http://thecodingwebsite.com/tutorials/photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul class="gallery">           
            <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/002.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=008f6dbb151fa0d6afdacea3ff6ef51f&user_id=125323824@N04";
    var src;
    $.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
            src = "http://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+ item.id   +"_"+ item.secret +"_s.jpg";
            srcc = "http://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+   item.id +"_"+ item.secret +"_n.jpg";

            $(".gallery").append('<li class="gallery-item"><a href="' + srcc + '"><img   src="'+src+'" /></a></li>');     


            if ( i == 5 ) return false;
        });
        var myPhotoSwipe = $(".gallery li a").photoSwipe({
            jQueryMobile: true,
            loop: false,
            enableMouseWheel: false,
            enableKeyboard: false
        });

        myPhotoSwipe.show(0);           
    });    
});
```

#### Update:

Plugin you found on the official web site was deprecated 2-3 years ago, author just didn't want to do anything with it any more. Another developer took it and severely changed the code, current version is 3.0.5 and it is far better the original plugin.

I believe, that plugin is not working because you are using newer version of jQuery and mentioned plugin can work only with jQuery version 1.7.3 and below, basically any jQuery version that still have function live.

You need to switch to this newer plugin. Just use attached code and it will work just like charm, you can even reuse everything from my example because GitHub documentation is somewhat unclear how to properly initialize this plugin.

If you can find it on official web page you will find it **[here](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe)**. If you carefully take a look you will see that code found on official web site and this one don't match a bit. If you carefully look at older plugin (just open its js file), you will see that it's using function **live**. If you are using newer version of jQuery, I would bet that this older code would work if you replace function **live(...** with function **on(...**.

### Solutions:

1. Switch to newer version of Photoswipe (you would need to use my code found above)
2. Edit old photoswipe js file and replace every mentioning of **live** function with function **on**.

Comment: some  explanation would be nice. Why did the asker "lose functionality"?

Comment: Only God know, she/he didn't put enough information. Probably: 1. code was not executed during document ready, 2. Photoswipe is initialized before async AJAX call ended.

Comment: If you don't think the question can be answered, then don't answer. Close instead. And by "add explanation", I meant "into the answer".

Comment: Don't think you can presume what I think. Question owner gave enough information to justify an answer. If this is not a correct answer or question owner don't understand it, he or she will ask for clarification.

Comment: sorry for mistake. when i create dynamic div it's not click able. i used js lib from http://photoswipe.com/

Comment: my header code:                                                                   <script type="text/javascript">
  
  // Set up PhotoSwipe with all anchor tags in the Gallery container 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   
   Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');
   
  }, false);
  
  
  </script>

Comment: remove my html comment it work fine, but when i used dynamic div its not working , thanx for reply

Comment: Lalit let's go from the beginning. Have you downloaded your plugin from official web site or from plugin github repository? Plus when you say "use dynamic divs" do you mean: 1. You have initialized Photoswipe plugin then added dynamic content or 2. You have dynamically added images then initialized Photoswipe plugin?

Comment: sorry for late reply. i downloaded plugin from official web site  photoswipe.com .i try to insert dynamic image using '<div class="gallery-item">' inside '<div  class="gallery-row">' then it show images but when i click on the image they not give any response.

Comment: I have updated my answer so take a look and try one of two proposed solutions. Then tell me please if that solved your problem?